# GraphQL: Use variable value as an alias

Tags: variables, alias, graphql

I have this GraphQL query:

```
{
  timeline(limit:10){
    eventType
    level: eventSeverity
  },  
}
```

I would like to set the 'eventSeverity' alias name using a variable, rather than the fixed name 'level'. Something like this:

```
query($name:String!)
{
  timeline(limit:10){
    eventType
    $name: eventSeverity
  },  
}
```

But running the above yields this error:

**Syntax Error GraphQL request (5:5) Expected Name, found $**

Is it possible to use a variable value as an alias name at all?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use dynamic field name in GraphQL, but what you can do is create a field that accepts a `name` argument, example

```
query($name: String!) {
  timeline(limit: 10) {
    eventType
    eventSeverity(name: $name) // Write a resolve function that returns timeline[name]
  }
}
```